# Find average of blob edge coordinates using AForge?

Tags: c#, aforge

I'm trying to find the average of the x and y coordinates of the blobs in a given bitmap image. As far as I can tell, I should be using

```
BlobCounter blobCounter = new BlobCounter();
blobCounter.ProcessImage((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image);
Blob[] blobs = blobCounter.GetObjectsInformation();
foreach (Blob blob in blobs)
{
     blobCounter.GetBlobsLeftAndRightEdges(Blob blob, out leftPoints, out rightPoints);

}
```

But a), I get an error, saying that "no overload for method GetBlobsLeftAndRightEdges takes 1 arguments", and b), I'm not sure where to go from there. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

well you try to fill an array with dimensional info
something like

public Rectangle[] Blobcounter.GetObjectsRectangles()   ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want avg of X & Y coordinates of all blobs, just to help you better. But in any case, if you want X and Y coordinates of each of the blob, you can replace the code in for loop with:

Rectangle rect = blob.Rectangle;

rect provides X and Y properties to get X and Y coordinates of the blob and some more properties which may help you in further processing..

Answer (score 0):

The following will solve your error a):

Declare the `leftPoints` and `rightPoints` List varaibles and remove the class name `Blob` when executing the `blobCounter.GetBlobsLeftAndRightEdges` method.

```
BlobCounter blobCounter = new BlobCounter();
blobCounter.ProcessImage((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image);
Blob[] blobs = blobCounter.GetObjectsInformation();

List<IntPoint> leftPoints;
List<IntPoint> rightPoints;

foreach (Blob blob in blobs)
{
     blobCounter.GetBlobsLeftAndRightEdges(blob, out leftPoints, out rightPoints);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaration for *List leftPoints = null;* and *List rightPoints = null;* is missing from the code. You need to allocate **out** paramters in calling code.